# My jquery cycle is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

When it was on my local directory(computer) the slides are working fine, but when I uploaded it to my hosting, it's just the first image that is showing up. I can't figure out what's wrong. TIA!

```
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://skywriterwebservices.com/bellaroma/plugins/jquery.js"></script>
                 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://skywriterwebservices.com/bellaroma/plugins/cycle-plugin.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#fade').cycle();
                });

            </script>



            <div id="featured" align="center">
                   <div id="fade">
                  <img src="img/slide1.jpg" width="800" height="230">
                  <img src="img/Slide2.jpg" width="800" height="230">
                  <img src="img/Slide3.jpg" width="800" height="230">
            </div>
```

I just changed the image path to local because this site is now allowing me to post image. Anyway. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clear image of the entire problem because I can't reproduce it, but it could be because your hosting server is running Linux and the file names are case-sensitive.

Try changing the files URLs of the second and third images to **img/slide2.jpg** and **img/slide3.jpg** if the files names start with lower-case *s*.